# angular doesn't work with multi step form

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax

I am new in using Angular and I use Angular 1.6
I have a form with multi steps, and each step sends with Ajax by clicking on next or prev button and data loaded on the page. these requests send by ajax jquery (don't send with angular)

I have a problem when I click on next or prev button and another step loaded when the page loaded: the angular $scope undefined and my code doesn't work (ng-repeat or...)

this is my jquery code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.jqGoToStep2', function(){

    /* Back To Step 2 */
    var did = $('#drf_id').val();

    backStep2Request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./back-step2",
        data: {'did': did},
        success: function(data){

            $('.jqTourContainer').html(data);

            /* Change Step */
            $('.tourTab li, div.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
            $('.tourTab li.step2, div#step2').addClass('active');

            //$('#drf_id').val(did);
        },
        beforeSend: function(){if(backStep2Request !== null) {backStep2Request.abort();backStep2Request = null;}}
    });

    return false;
});
```

AND my html view is simillar to:
Angular:

```
<div  ng-repeat="date in dates">

{{date.startDate}}
{{date.StartTime}}

</div>
```

I use $rootScope and factory but it isn't solved.

what's your suggestion could help me?

Comment: Don't mix jQuery and Angular ...

Comment: Your code doesn't look like `AngularJS`. Why don't you use `ngClick` and `$http` instead of `.on('click'....` and `$.ajax`?